# Does the GN-WS50G-RH wireless card work in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, 64-bit, laptop, 32-bit

Alright so I've given up with my RT3090BC4 wifi card, someone has offered me their old laptops chip to put in mine but their motherboard is fried so we can't boot and see if the chip works on a LiveCD. Does anyone know if this chip works out of the box or whether I can download drivers for it if necessary? I've tried google and the forums but nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old Dell Laptop had the Gigabyte version of this card the card was subbed out to a few smaller outfits and I believe Fujitsu also carry a version of the same chipset and from what I remember it worked OOTB with no problems.

I do remember the power usage was a bit juicy but apart from that I think (From memory) this card is fine.

I hope this helps.

NB just checked a good blog site for this card and the HP 210 ships with it. The blogger stated everything apart from the shortcut keys worked OOTB so I would suggest the answer is yes

Comment: Thanks muchly, I couldn't find a thing to suggest that it did or it didn't. It's the Gigabyte version I'm getting (sorry I should've specified) so your reply was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to look for another card. The RT3090BC4 should work.
Be sure to use the newest kernel for up to date hardware support...

The GN-Card should work though:

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/old-bt3final-support/15333-most-recommended-minipcie-wifi-card.html?langid=3

Hope this helps